# Как в schedule передать асинхронную функцию

Tags: python, telethon, schedule

Пишу клиентского бота на `telethon` и потребовалось отправлять определённое сообщение каждые *n* секунд. Поэтому я нагуглил про библиотеку `schedule`, и она хорошо работает с обычными функциями, но, логично, при передаче в неё асинхронной функции появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\...\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 467, in _dispatch_update
     await callback(event)
   File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\...\main_2.py", line 45, in start
     await schedule.every(5).seconds.do(all_orders)
TypeError: object Job can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Мне бы хотелось узнать как можно провернуть эту "аферу". Ну или существует ли другой способ для реализации. Заранее спасибо.

Вот код:

```
async def all_orders():
    await client.send_message('@_bot', 'привет')


def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(5)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('@_bot',)))
async def main(event):
    if event.message.message != 'Все заказы':
        if event.message.message[0] in numbers:
            orders_list.append(event.message.message)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('me',)))
async def start(event):
    if event.message.message == 'Начать':
        await schedule.every(5).seconds.do(all_orders)
        Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

UPT:
А, ну и без `await` перед `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(all_orders)` выкидывает вот такую ошибку:

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [aiocron](https://github.com/gawel/aiocron). рекомендован в документации Telethon

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы передавать асинхронные функции можно использовать [aioschedule](https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]